# Using fail2ban for ELK clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fail2ban

Is it a good idea to add an additional layer of security by adding fail2ban for ELK clusters? If so how can we achieve that?

Does anyone have used fail2ban for this kind of setup?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I've removed the Apache Kafka tag from your question as it's not clear how it's related. I'm assuming by ELK you mean Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana? Are you talking about SSH access into boxes running these, or something different?

Comment: Thanks Robin.. Yes, apart from SSH, can we use fail2ban to secure ELK services?